# Are husband and wife, associated/affected by each others' sins?

Tags: marriage, women, sin, valmiki

Is it true, that husband is associated in his wife's sin but the wife is not associated in her husband's sin?

Example: Robber Valia's wife told him that I have not associated with your sin. Later he became great sage Valmiki.

Is there any scripture reference in Hinduism about it?

Comment: Wife doesn't incur sin, if she is dedicated to her husband completely. In such case, she surrenders the "doership" & does all her actions under husband's command. Hence, irrespective of wife's action, she doesn't incur the sin herself. Now, not incurring sin, doesn't mean she will not have to bear bad results. Due to her attachment with her husband, she might have to go through the hardships, her husband may face. But she naturally develops strength to face those. Adolf Hitler & Eva Braun can be a classic example, IMO.

Comment: Means you are asking whether a wife gets affected by her husband's sins or not?

Comment: Yes, @Rickross. and also vice-versa.

Comment: Ok that means you are also asking whether a husband gets affected by his wife's sins? @YogeshBorad

Comment: Sorry, @Rickross. I have not mentioned in both situation in question. But if you know both situations then tell me, otherwise only tell me, Wife is an associate in Husband's sin?

Comment: If u are also asking about whether a wife's sins get transferred to her husband or not then I can answer.. for the reverse situation I have to check.. for the first Q I know the answer.. @YogeshBorad

Comment: Half the punya done by husband goes to wife. None of the papa done by husband goes to wife. Half the papa done by wife goes to husband. None of the punya does by wife goes to husband. Source - upanyasa.

Answer (score 13):

#### Husband being associated in wife's sins

The wife's sins definitely affect the husband. This is mentioned in the scriptures.

> *Mantridoshascha rAjAnam **jAyAdoshah patim yathA** |
>
> TathA prApnotyasandeham shishyapApam gurum priye ||*
>
> Just like a king gets affected by the sins committed by his ministers,
> **a husband gets affected by the sins committed by his wife,** likewise,
> without any doubt, O Beloved, a disciple's sins affect the Teacher
> (Guru).
> [KulArnava Tantram 11.110]

#### Wife being associated in husband's sins

Need to check.