# Side effects of Initiation by a Guru?

Tags: sin, guru, initiation

The guru at the time of initiation takes on himself the sins of the disciple and suffers so much from physical maladies.

My question:

1. Is this true? Is this why many gurus suffer from various diseases?
2. Are there any reliable sources from our scriptures that can support this statement, if true?

Comment: taking sins of disciples? That sounds weird to me..

Comment: Everything is energy, vibration and frequency, when someone with higher energy, vibration and frequency comes in touch with someone with lower energy, vibration and frequency .... will there be no energy transformation??? @LogTran

Comment: Whenever two people meet, sin transfer happens or what? High sinner sin gets reduced and low sinner quota increases. You killed the logic itself.

Comment: @LogTran When you are on the path of spirituality then logical thinking has to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting the verse from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27656/4732):

> Mantridoshascha rAjAnam jAyAdoshah patim yathA |
> TathA prApnotyasandeham **shishyapApam gurum priye** ||
>
> Just like a king gets affected by the sins committed by his ministers,
> a husband gets affected by the sins committed by his wife, likewise,
> without any doubt, O Beloved, **a disciple's sins affect the Teacher
> (Guru).**
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 11.110*

This means that if after initiation, the disciple commits a sin, the Guru will also have to share that guilt. That is why the Guru is to accept a disciple only after checking whether the disciple is qualified for the initiation and of a good conduct or not.

Also, the Guru burns the sins of the disciple by Shaktipata etc during initiation but he does not accept the disciple's sins.

Comment: So it means sins of the disciple affect guru after initiation not during it? Right? @rickross

Comment: Yes that’s right @Just_Do_It

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Rickross' answer, the Rudrayamala says

> vichArya yatAnAd vidhivat shishya-sangraham Achared/anyathA shishyadoshena narakastho bhaved guruh//
>
> Meaning : If the guru initiates without testing someone according to rule just for making more disciple, he goes to hell because of the faults of the disciple.

Reference: satramulak bharatiya shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, RMIC, vol.2, page 775

Answer (score 0):

A guru has to assume responsibility for the disciple's sin and suffering.

> ELDER SISTER-IN-LAW: "Will you please give us some instruction?"
>
> MASTER (affectionately): "I don't give initiation. **If a guru gives
>   initiation he must assume responsibility for the disciple's sin and
>   suffering.** The Divine Mother has placed me in the state of a child.
>   Perform the Siva Puja as I told you. Come here now and then. We shall
>   see what happens later on through the will of God. I asked you to
>   chant the name of Hari at home. Are you doing that?"
>
> ELDER SISTER-IN-LAW: "Yes."

The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, ch 22, Advice to an actor, May 24, 1884