# Does guru get good karma of disciple?

Tags: guru, initiation

The question [Side effects of Initiation by a Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34801/side-effects-of-initiation-by-a-guru).

As per the question above, guru gets bad karma of disciple.

What about good karma of disciple? Does guru share good karma and enjoy as well? Logically this must be true.

Comment: Guru doesn't automatically get bad karma of disciple, Guru by his will takes upon the suffering on himself originally intended for the disciple because Guru has realized his self and suffering is only of the body but disciple hasn't so disciple would have suffered. No need to take good karma, they will exhaust in time.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria none of the answers say so

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria You are 200% correct.

Comment: @LogTran He actually means real ie Brahmavid Gurus.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria even bad karma will exhaust in time.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria This logic makes no sense at all.

Comment: @LogTran Bad karma results in suffering, the time period for the same a disciple can utilize to make spiritual progress. Solely from spiritual point of view, both good and bad karma are obstacles but good karma don't make you suffer, do they? Guru takes the effect of bad karmas to free the disciple of the same.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria same can be said to support the opposite case well. Good karma results in enjoyment and thus one may forget his spiritual practice. Therefore good karma also need to be removed by guru. Bad karma can be a blessing as well, then one will think that I have to get out of suffering and have more commitment to spiritual practice.