# transfer of karmafal

Tags: karma, shloka

Are there any slokas from *any* scriptures that depict the transfer of karmafaal(result of someone's deeds).

I'll give you a scenerio. Suppose a person earns his living by doing something, yet he makes some monthly extra cash by selling meat, cutting animals, selling their flesh, tusks, fur etc. Now his son is a normal person, not a devotee, or a yogi nor someone involved in any dharmic deeds. He is just a normal being who does no bad no good. Yet he is living by his father's earning. So, is the son also sinful?

Comment: Yes. The son is taking something equivalent to 'apatra dana' from his father.

Comment: Yes, wealth is a form of fruit of actions and hence it can be either good or bad wealth depending upon the actions behind it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path also includes right livelihood.  http://www.bhagavatam-katha.com/story-krishna-only-accepts-love-and-affection-krishnas-visit-to-palace-of-duryodana-and-house-of-vidura/ Yogi Krishna rejected food of Duryodhana because it was bought from corruption and deception of Kauravas, but ate instead at Vidura's house who was reincarnation of Yamaraj, Dharamraj.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am partially answering the question without going into the actual scenario given in the question.

Yes, there are some circumstances, where one person has to suffer for the misdeeds of others.

Quoting from [Devi Bhagavatam 7.16](https://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam35.htm):

> His father, out of greed for money, is deprived of intellect and so
> has sold away his son. The Brâhmin is certainly very cruel and sinful.
> There is no doubt in this. When one goes to Gayâ or one performs an
> As’vamedha sacrifice or when one offers a blue bull (Nila Vrisabha),
> one does so on the consideration that one would desire to have many
> sons. **Moreover the King has to suffer for one-sixth of the sins
> committed by anyone in his Kingdom. There is no doubt in this.
> Therefore the King ought certainly to prohibit any man when he wants
> to do a sinful act.** Why then did you not prevent this man when he
> desired to sell his son? O King! You are the son of Tris’anku;
> especially you are born in the Solar line of Kings. So how have you
> desired, being born an Âryâ, to do an act becoming an An-Âryâ
> (non-aryan). If you take my word and quickly free this Brâhmin boy,
> you will certainly derive virtue in your body. Your father was
> converted into a Chândâla by a curse but I sent him in his very body
> to the Heavens. And you are well acquainted with this fact.

Moreover, as shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27656/4732), a Guru (Spiritual Teacher) gets a share of sins committed by his disciple. A husband gets affected by sins committed by his wife and a king gets the shares of sins committed by his ministers.

> *Mantridoshascha rAjAnam jAyAdoshah patim yathA |
>
> TathA prApnotyasandeham shishyapApam gurum priye ||*
>
> Just like a king gets affected by the sins committed by his ministers,
> a husband gets affected by the sins committed by his wife, likewise,
> without any doubt, O Beloved, a disciple's sins affect the Teacher
> (Guru).
> [KulArnava Tantram 11.110]

So, although generally, one has to suffer for deeds that one oneself has committed, sometimes it can be that we will be facing the results of bad deeds done by others. Like Guru of his Shishyas, a king of his subjects, a husband of his wife etc.

In Hinduism we can also do Karmas on behalf of others. So, transfer of Karmaphala is possible.

Suppose, you take bath, then it is understood that you yourself will get purified but if scripture says that by bathing yourself you can purify someone else then it's clear that transfer of Karmaphala has occurred.
And, this is what is stated in the following verse:

> When an occasion for bathing arrives **in the case of a person
> suffering from a disease, one, who is healthy, should bathe ten times
> and touch him. By it, the diseased person becomes purified.** (53)
>
> **Yama Smriti**