# Question related to papa and punya shastra

Tags: scripture, vedas, vedanta, kali-yuga, smarta

I've heard that after a marriage:

When a wife does a sin, the entire karma (100%) of that sin goes to her husband.
When a wife does a punya, the entire fruit (100%) of that punya goes to herself only.

When a husband does a sin, the entire karma (100%) of that sin goes to himself.
When a husband does a punya, the half of the fruit (50%) of that punya goes to his wife.

I am not sure how this can be true?
In that case, if the wife commits many mistakes/sins, the husband accumulates papa karma unknowingly? How does the husband come out of this?
What punya he should do to avoid this?

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate but same topic --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27656/4732