# Do husband and wife go to heaven or hell together?

Tags: marriage, heaven, hell, wife, husband

Do husband and wife go to heaven or hell together ?

It is being said that [sin of the wife is absorbed by the husband.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27656/23709)

Plus it is quite well known that a Pativrata wife takes the husband to heaven along with her self.

?

Comment: a link is not a source. please put the source in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are husband and wife, associated/affected by each others' sins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27651/are-husband-and-wife-associated-affected-by-each-others-sins)

Comment: ...and no. question is asking for opinions.

Comment: it is not asking for opinions @SwamiVishwananda. it is asking a perfectly valid scriptural question, one that you are likely to be unaware of. river - a sati (who enters agni of her dead husband) lives with him svarga for as many years (or thousand of years) as number of hairs on her body that got burnt. a pativrata who follows vidhva dharma, also joins her husband in afterlife. obviously they won't go together if one of them died first. also, not ALL the sin of wife is absorbed by husband - only half. also half his punya goes to his wife.