Does husband get wife's karma?
Does husband get a share of wife's sin?
What do the scriptures say about this issue?

Marriage vows enjoin a couple to share each other's joy, sorrow and karma as common dharma.

Please give scriptural proof

See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27656

Most of the Hindu worship that happens today are based on only Tantras ..they are Lord Shiva's words so more valid than any other scriptures IMO .. also that is the only reference I have. @aryaninvader
